# How to enable parse server rest api

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ec2, parse-server

I have set up parse server on AWS. Everything works except rest API.

How/where do I set the rest API key? Is additional set up on AWS required (ports etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

When using Parse.com, we used to prefix classes with '1':

```
ParseIt.connection.request('PUT', '/1/classes/' + parse_class, json.dumps({...
```

Now, replace '1' with 'parse':

```
ParseIt.connection.request('PUT', '/parse/classes/' + parse_class, json.dumps({...
```

Make sure you start  parse with your restAPIkey (I am passing as a command line argument).

The above should work regardless of where you run Parse.